# Calling stored procedure in ssis 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble with a task in my SSIS 2012 package. I am creating a package to (in order):

1. truncate data in a SQL Server table
2. populate that table via a flat text file
3. then executing a stored procedure
4. then export the data to Excel

The table I am using is called `dbo.ClientData` in a database called `SalesQuota`

The first two tasks work fine but I am having trouble with executing the stored procedure (via execute SQL task) in the package. I've tried everything from clicking retain same connection to true to trying to writing out the SQL Server procedure in the task. But I keep getting an error. So, I used SQL Search in Management Studio to see where the procedure is stored and it shows that it is in 3 different databases in the server could that be the reason for the error? I googled and saw something regarding mapping a variable (?) to the task but I couldn't find the parameters of the procedure.

This is the error I got

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "execute [dbo].[up_client_sp]" failed with the following error:
>   Invalid object name 'SalesQuota.dbo.clientstatusgather'.
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an ADO.NET connection to the database and use that that connection in the SQL Task that calles the store procedure.  There is also a property call IsQueryStoredProcedure that should be set to true.

You can set up parameters on the Parameter Mapping tab of the SQL Task Editor and if your SP returns any data, you can capture it using the Result Set tab in the SQL Task Editor.  But you should only need to do that if your SP is actually returning a result set that you want to capture.

Comment: thank you for the reply but shouldn't I use an OLE DB connection since for the previous two tasks I used OLE DB connection? and the connection was good but the package always fails at the third step, and I did have the IsQueryStoredProcedure set to true, still no difference unfortunately. Also how would I know what the parameters are for the procedure? when I open the procedure there is no @-- near the procedure statement and I read those are the parameter names

Comment: We use OLEDB for all our basic SQL execute statements, but for Stored Procedures call we use an ADO.NET connection.  I'm actually not sure of the complete reason (you can look it up and compare if you like) - but I have receive the same error as you when I mistakenly set them up as OLEDB.  I don't understand what your question is in relation to the parameters.  In the Parameter Mapping tab you but the SSIS Variable Name in one field and the SQL Parameter Name in  another field. Do you know the names of the parameters?

Comment: I am not sure of the name of the parameters I tried finding them by certain codes that let you view the procedure name etc but it always end up with no rows, after going through the servers I realized the procedure is stored in another server as well. we use two servers one for testing but it still has official data and another for the official databases exclusively. In the official db the procedure is found only once and in the other testing db it is found 4 times maybe i should use the official server procedure?

Comment: From SQL Mgt Studio you can right click on the SP and select 'Script Stored Procedure as' - select Execute or Create and you will get all the info you need about the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Sp_ helptext ' procname' will script the stored procedure for you. And use ? as variable space holder In your SSIS package for your parameters. I'm assuming you're using sql task. I'll also suggest you use oledb connection.